# Pdf.Js Express - Mouse Hover Event Listener

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

We are using Pdf.JS Express Viewer. We are able to catch doubleclick event via

```
 ViewerInstance.Core.documentViewer.addEventListener("dblClick",handleDblClick);
```

But we need also mouse hover events on each word.

This library is a kind of advanced version of Mozillas' Pdf.Js that wraps around that library and adding more features.

So if we can get doubleClicked word, i thought it is possible to catch events on mouse hover on words.

I need a way to catch these events along with hovered word Itself. Thank you for your helps

Comment: what is the event you want to happen when the mouse hovers?

Comment: I will create list of hovered words.

Answer (score 0):

There were two methods that I could find. One, is by listening for a mouse over event on certain annotations, in this [example](https://pdfjs.community/t/need-to-highlight-annotation-on-mouse-hover/1177/4) they check if the mouse is over the **annotation**, then change its color:

```
let highlightedAnnot = null;
  let lastHighlightedColor = null;

  // Change this to change the highlight color
  const highlightColor = new instance.Core.Annotations.Color(255,0,0,1);

  instance.Core.documentViewer.addEventListener('mouseMove', (e) => {

    // Check if an annotation is under the mouse
    const annot = instance.Core.annotationManager.getAnnotationByMouseEvent(e)
    if(annot) {

     // Break early if its already highlighted
      if(highlightedAnnot) return;

      // Make sure its a highlight annotation
      if(annot instanceof instance.Core.Annotations.TextHighlightAnnotation) {
        const {R,G,B,A} = annot.StrokeColor

        // Store the original color of the annotation so we can revert back to it when its unhovered
        lastHighlightedColor = new instance.Core.Annotations.Color(R,G,B,A);

       // Store the instnace of the annot so we can revert it when its unhovered
        highlightedAnnot = annot;

        // Set the color and redraw
        annot.StrokeColor = highlightColor;
        instance.Core.annotationManager.redrawAnnotation(annot)
      }
    } else if(highlightedAnnot) {
     // Revert the annotation back to its original state when unhovered
      highlightedAnnot.StrokeColor = lastHighlightedColor;
      instance.Core.annotationManager.redrawAnnotation(highlightedAnnot)
      highlightedAnnot = null;
      lastHighlightedColor = null;
    }
  })
```

another method is by using the `customOverlayHandler` which as per the [docs](https://pdfjs.express/api/UI.html#.setAnnotationContentOverlayHandler__anchor):

> A function that takes an annotation and returns a DOM Element, which
> is rendered as a tooltip when hovering over the annotation. Returning
> null or false will render nothing. Returning 'undefined' will use
> default behavior.

```
Example
aboutraw—
WebViewer(...)
  .then(function(instance) {
    instance.UI.setAnnotationContentOverlayHandler(annotation => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Created by: ${annotation.Author}`));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Created on ${annotation.DateCreated}`));
        return div;
    });
  });
```

As far as custom hover states, I don't think PDF.Js has an api for handling customized hover states. The best they have is checking for **annotations**, which will be necessary.

Comment: There wont be any annotations, only pdf files which contains selectable texts.

Comment: The only way to select hovered words in PDF.js is by annotating the words first.

Comment: did I answer your question @AliHaydarGüleç?

Comment: I will definetly try it and reply back